# Confirm delete modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, confirm

I have a problem with modal confirm delete. Modal show but can't confirm delete. This is my code.

Hhml:

```
<button type="submit" email-confirm></button>
```

Jquery function:

```
$('button[email-confirm]').click(function (e) {
    var type = $(this).attr('type:submit');
    if (!$('#dialog').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="dialog" class="modal modal-block" role="dialog"><p>Do you want to delete?</p><button id="dialogConfirm">Confirm</button><button id="dialogCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>');
    } 
    $('#dialogConfirm').attr('type:submit', type);
    $('#dialog').modal({ show: true });
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" id="button" email-confirm></button>

$('#button').click(function (e) {
var type = $(this).attr('type:submit');
if (!$('#dialog').length) {
    $('body').append('<div id="dialog" class="modal modal-block" role="dialog"><p>Do you want to delete?</p><button id="dialogConfirm">Confirm</button><button id="dialogCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></div>');
} 
$('#dialogConfirm').attr('type:submit', type);
$('#dialog').modal({ show: true });
return false;
})
```

Comment: Button on click can't confirm.

Comment: @DuyTong If you can tell me what error you are getting, i think i can help you

Comment: I can't press the confirmation button.

Comment: @DuyTong okay I can see what you are trying to say. i think your button has no value.
try using this `<button type="submit" id="button" email-confirm>Confirm</button>`